# Error install react app with npm

Tags: windows, reactjs, react-native, npm

I've problem when installing `react app` with `npm`.

I also have downgrade my version of npm to version 3, but still error. And especially my internet connection is very good.

Thanks for your answer!

[image]

Comment: as the error says you have problem with your network connection

Comment: can you include the command you used that resulted this.

Comment: remove proxy and retry. This is clearly a network issue.Use create-react-native-app and this has to be installed with global -g flag. Also make sure you have minimum requirements for installing it: npm version and node version. restart the terminal and retry, it should work. Sometimes i use 2G network and this command works for me.

Comment: hi, @abdul this the command i used: create-react-app myapp

Answer (score 0):

**Try following solution**

- Install yarn `npm install -g yarn`
- Disable antivirus
- Enable npm registry on firewall